# Does excessive cooing mean early talking?

Tags: infant, language-development

My grandson is three months old and is cooing/making noises ALL the time, except when he is crying and sleeping, of course. Does that have any correlation to talking? Meaning, are there statistics that state that he will talk real words early on?

Comment: +1 what an interesting question! My own experience was that my 2nd child made more vocalizations & earlier than my first child (who ended up needing speech therapy bc his speech was delayed) and my 3rd was about even with my 2nd. Both 2 & 3 started using words around the same age. I always attributed it to having an older sibling to mimic. Then, my 4th child was quieter, and spoke later than 2 & 3, almost to the point of concern, but now is an incessant chatterbox. So, now, I’m not so sure it’s all sibling exposure like I thought.

Comment: I love this question, but can't find any good sources on the matter.  (Holding out hope that it exists and someone with more relevant experience will find it!)

Answer (score 3):

No. My daughter cooed a lot but didn't start talking until she was more than 1.5 yr. She could repeat sounds that we were making before that, but she didn't really start using them on her own until 1.5 yr.

Answer (score 0):

Children are cooing and making other noises for several reasons:
1. They need atention. Some children need more, some less. After finding out that making noises brings parents attention - they migt be interested to "talk" alot.
2. They need to develop their vical instruments - be it mouth, vocal cords, centers in brain or hearing. There is a pocibility that it is hard for child to ajust some of his vocal "instruments" correctly so he/she needs to "talk" alot.

All in all the thing you mentioned - is not bad or good by itself. But you can make it into something good if you will respond to a child. Mimiking his sounds - to let him know that you hear him/her, helping him/her separate some words from sounds he/she makes. (Like dadadada... you say:Dad. Child: dadadada... you: Dad Every sound that at list partly resambles some word - can be used to create word for your child.) If you will use this opportunity to communicate with your child and to help him/her find correct words - your child will start talking earlier.